# Implode Array to set in insert Query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Good Day!

I have this code that will `explode the variable value by comma (,)` and

```
$tokenize = explode(',', $secondaryRoleCode);
foreach($tokenize as $compare)
{
   $compare = trim($compare);
   $query_secondaryRole = $this->db->query("select ID from role where RoleName like '%".$compare."%';");
   $get_secondaryID = $query_secondaryRole->row_array();
}
```

And after that I just want to get the `result array with the name of variable` of `$get_secondaryID` and I will use in the insert query like this:

```
$this->db->set('SecondaryRoleID', $get_secondaryID['ID']. ',');
$this->db->insert('batch_structure_details');
$id_activity = $this->db->insert_id();
```

This is the result of `$get_secondaryID` when I print_r:

```
 Array
(
    [ID] => 2
)
Array
(
    [ID] => 3
)
```

I just need have an output of like this: `3, 6, 9`
My problem is how can I concat those value.

The value `3, 6, 9` is the one I will use to insert in `this: $this->db->set('SecondaryRoleID', );`

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question, it is quite confusing what you are asking :)

Comment: `implode` is the opposite of `explode`

Comment: @pNre I have problem in using the implode. Is there any way I can iterate the array values and concat this by comma?

Comment: You should probably make an array of `$get_secondaryID['ID']` in your foreach loop and then `implode` it.

Comment: I edited my code above.

Comment: make $get_secondaryID to $get_secondaryID[]. then appy my sample code 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple `foreach()`

```
$ids = '';
foreach($get_secondaryID as $sec_id)
{
     if($ids !="")
     {
         $ids .= ",".$sec_id['id'];
     }
     else
     {
         $ids = $sec_id['id'];
     }
}
echo $ids; // will give you something like this 2,34,6,23,11
$this->db->set('SecondaryRoleID', $ids);
```

**OR** you can use `implode()

```
$ids = '';
$arr=[];
foreach($get_secondaryID as $sec_id)
{
         $arr[] = $sec_id['id'];
}
$ids = implode(',', $arr);
echo $ids; // will give you something like this 2,34,6,23,11
$this->db->set('SecondaryRoleID', $ids);
```

Comment: In the first sample code you gave it just echo only the last array?

Comment: Sorry My mistake. I have corrected it in the first sample code .

Comment: I didn't get what you mean that "There's an error in $arr = [];". It worked for me.

Comment: With your first sample code above. I am just wondering why it only output the last value in array? I mean, in the sample array above, with your code, it only output 9, 9.

Comment: And also it always output like this: 3, 3 not 3, 3, 3 or 3, 6, 9

Comment: When I print_r the $get_secondaryID it has the result like this: Array
(
    [ID] => 2
)
Array
(
    [ID] => 3
)

Comment: You think I have a problem with this: $get_secondaryID = $query_secondaryRole->row_array();???

Comment: I just edited the above result of $get_secondaryID when I print_r the variable.

Comment: you said $a[1]['id'] is 3, again the same $a[1]['id'] gives 6 and  again the same $a[1]['id'] gives 9. it doesn't makes any sense. Here the array value is getting replaced only.

Comment: Hope Your values in the $get_secondaryID is like :$get_secondaryID[1]['id']=3;
  $get_secondaryID[1]['name']=manu;
  $get_secondaryID[2]['id']=6;
  $get_secondaryID[2]['name']=anu;
  $get_secondaryID[3]['id']=9;
  $get_secondaryID[3]['name']=nu;
So the 1st sample code will be...
  $arr=[];
 $ids = '';
foreach($get_secondaryID as $sec_id)
{
     if($ids !="")
     {
         $ids .= ",".$sec_id['id'];
     }
     else
     {
         $ids = $sec_id['id'];
     }
}
echo $ids; // it will give the output like what you desired. If it's not, then there is some problem with array value you gave.

Comment: change $get_secondaryID to $get_secondaryID[]. Now appy my sample code 1 or 2.

Comment: Your great!!!:) Thank you so much.:) But can you explain me what is the difference when I change $get_secondaryID to $get_secondaryID[]?

Comment: $get_secondaryID[] is now only becomes a multidimensional array. Before that your array was like $get_secondaryID['id']. It was like you were replacing the value of $get_secondaryID['id'] each time you go through 'foreach' loop. Now it becomes for each 'foreach' loop $get_secondaryID[1]['id'],$get_secondaryID[2]['id'],$get_secondaryID[3]['id']. Now it becomes as we write a functions 'push' values to an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `for()`

```
$ids = '';
$size = sizeof($get_secondaryID);
for($i=0; $i<=$size-1; $i++)
{
     $ids .= $get_secondaryID[$i]['id'];

     if($i != $size-1)
     {
         $ids .= ',';
     }
}

echo $ids; // will give you something like this 2,34,6,23,11

$this->db->set('SecondaryRoleID', $ids);
```

**OR** you can use `implode()`, but here since it is a multidimensional array you have to use `array_map()` also

```
$arr = array_map(function($sec){ return $sec['id']; }, $arr);
$ids = implode(',', $arr);
echo $ids; // will give you something like this 2,34,6,23,11
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. the for() I will just insert that code insoide the for each()? I try to put it outside the for each() but it result only the last array?

Answer (score 0):

```
    I think this following example will help you
    <?php 

    if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
        $demo = array();
        $demo = implode(",",$_POST['dem']);
        var_dump($demo);
    }
    ?>

    <form method="post" action="del.php">
        <input type="text" name="dem[]" />
        <input type="text" name="dem[]" />
        <input type="text" name="dem[]" />
        <input type="submit" name="sub" value=""/>
    </form>

while submitting data[post], getting an array named $demo ,given in example, just separate it, and push it to the query
```